# Understanding the output of this code in C language

Tags: c, output

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void main()

{
    int a,b;
    char *cp;

    a=511;

    cp=&a;

    b=*cp;

    *cp=10;

    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,*cp);
}
```

It is giving out **266 -1 10** in gcc with a warning : assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
cp=&a;
I know cp is a char pointer so it is giving me a warning.

I am not able to understand output for a and b;

Comment: Narrow Conversion when assigning an int to a char. This is an example of Unsafe Type Conversion.

Comment: That output indicates that you ran the code on a little-endian system. On a big-endian system, the output will be different. That's the reason for the warning. The code is broken, and should be fixed before you run it.

Comment: If you use hexadecimal representation you might get more interesting and clear picture.

Comment: @user3386109: Well, the reason for the warning is that he's assigning to 'char *' from an incompatible pointer type 'int *'. Ie he needs a cast. The code is non-portable rather than broken. Well, it's broken now but if he fixed it it would be non-portable :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers you get will depend on how your particular processor is storing an integer. On a 32 bit "little endian" machine, it will store the number 511 (1FF in hexadecimal), somewhere in memory as:

```
FF 01 00 00
```

from lowest memory location (FF) to highest(00). You then take the "address of a" and say "make this a character pointer" and assign it to "cp".

Except you miss out the "make this" part and gcc does this for you - this is why you get the warning. To remove the warning you must tell gcc: "yes, I want to do this". You do that by explicitly taking the integer pointer and making into a character pointer:

```
cp = (char *)&a;
```

OK. So now you have a character pointer pointing to the first address where you have an FF stored. You dereference this (with *cp) to get a *signed char*. The value of this is -1 which you put in b.

You then change the FF to 0A (10 in decimal). The memory now looks like this:

```
0A 01 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
    int a,b;
    char *cp;

    a=511;

    cp=&a;
```

The range of the `char` type variable is from `[-128 to 127]` and of `int` is `[-32,768 to 32,767]` or `[-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647]`.

So, when you store a larger data type that requires more bits into a smaller data type which requires fewer bits, then it will lead to narrow conversion, more properly known as Unsafe Type Conversion.

Try to assign value to `a` which is in the range of the `char` i.e. `[-127 to 128]` then you will get a predictable output, otherwise, it can be Undefined Behaviour.